# Action not Found - play migration from 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

While running sbt run:

`sbt run -Dconfig.resource="modules/conf/application.conf"`
(my `application.conf` file is under modules.)

Project is a multi module project.

When I run `http://localhost:9000`, it gives me "Action not found" error.

`Action not found For request 'GET /' These routes have been tried, in this order:`

How to resolve this? The same error I got when I migrated from play 2.2 to 2.6 so community suggested me to do step by step incremental updates so I started with 2.3 and now I am in 2.4 migration but still the issue is same. please someone help me here .

Comment: Have you tried [Play's official migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration24)?

Comment: @AminMal I have migrated all the required code by following migration guide but still seems like routing is not working. can you help me here.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what versions of Scala/sbt/Java you're using?

Comment: @AminMal I am using sbt-0.13.15,scala 2.11.12  and Java 1.8 versions

Comment: Your application cannot recognize your config file(obviously), I read the play documentation, and It indicates to pass config files like this: `-Dconfig.resource=path/to/config/application.cong` (without quotation marks), so instead of `-Dconfig.resource="modules/conf/application.conf"` try `-Dconfig.resource=/modules/conf/application.conf` and let me know if it worked.

Comment: @AminMal I tried same like how you mentioned : Dconfig.resource=/modules/conf/application.conf still facing same issue.

Action not found

Comment: Where is your routes file located?

Comment: @AminMal route file is also under modules/conf/A.routes. I have 6 modules in my multi module project. each one has its own route file under conf directory.

I don't have any route file as well as application.conf file in route directory. i.e., root-directory conf folder.

application.conf file is present in module1/conf/application.conf so while running sbt I am pointing to the module location in order to get through the configuration  error.

Comment: Okay so maybe you need to pass routes file location as well beside application.conf file. Have you tried this?

Comment: @AminMal are you suggesting me to try like this :  ?

-Dconfig.resource=/modules/conf/application.conf,polaris.core.Routes

Comment: I tried bt giving both files while running sbt still the issue is same :

-Dconfig.resource=/modules/conf/application.conf,polaris.core.Routes

still I get Action not Found. @AminMal